# Can't enable my local area connection in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, dns

This problem really ruffles my feathers the past couple of days.

It started a couple a days ago, when my internet suddenly was gone. So I went searching on the internet to look for some answers.

I've done a lot but nothing seems to work, things I've tried:

1. ROUTE DELETE 0.0.0.0
2. Reinstall drivers
3. Virus scans
4. Router off and on
5. Modem off and on
6. Looked if everything was connected properly
7. IP renew release
8. DNS flush
9. Google DNS
10. Manually attach IP address

I tried to do a system recovery, but that doesn't work and I don't know why :-(

I was using McAfee Total Protection 2013, but since I read something about that blocking your connection I switched to Windows Defender.

My other computer is working, though, which is connected the same way (wired via the same router). On that pc I have internet access.
I'm running Windows 7 64-bit.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What antivirus are you using? I had a similar issue with Bitdefender Free installed.

Comment: Does an ethernet adapter exist?  Is said device being reported as "working properly"

Comment: Yup, check Ramhound's advice. Go into Device Manager and make sure that the device is actually there and working. If it is try and Rollback the drivers if possible

Comment: Can you do a `pathping` to google? See what ping returns, see how far you can get. Can you even connect to your gateway?

Comment: @kobaltz:
Right now, I am using Windows Defender. Just a few hours ago it was McAfee, but I read something about that blocking your connection.

Comment: @Ramhound:
I guess so, it's called a 'Local Area Connection' with driver name: "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller". If I try to enable that, it says Enabled but stays disabled. The device status says: "This device is working properly"

Comment: @r3mus:
The command is: 'path ping www.google.com' (without quotes)? If so, my following output is: "Unable to resolve target system name www.google.com".

Hope I have you guys informed well enough.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the results of `ipconfig /all`? Also if you can test `ping X.X.X.X` where xxxx is your default gateway, that'd be great!

Comment: The output from ipconfig /all for the Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection is:
DHCP is enabled
Autoconfig is enabled
Subnetmask is 255.255.0.0 (should be 255.255.255.0 ?)
IPv4: 169.254.149.236
NetBIOS over Tcpip: enabled

I can't ping to my default gateway, since there is none. The field is empty in cmd screen.

Comment: Does it work in Safe Mode with Networking?  Have you tried booting to a Linux LiveCD (or alike) to see if the network adapter work from there?

Comment: OK, and what happens if you set your IP address/subnet mask manually? Assuming your router is 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1, make sure the IP is in the proper range (192.168.0.2-254, or 192.168.1.2-254).

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Unidentified network Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/666988/unidentified-network-windows-7) asked yesterday. Please add updated information to the existing question. Don't post repeatedly as it only adds confusion.

Comment: @CharlieRB 
Yes, I know, but since I did some research myself and find some things out I thought I could better make a new one.

I deleted the old one now.

Comment: @r3mus
Tried that, but did not work as well.
I really don't know what the problem is here..

Comment: If you set the IP address, can you ping the router? Can you do an ipconfig with the static IP?

Comment: I get: "Request timed out."

Comment: Can you ping 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yes, that works (at least something works). That's localhost, right?

Comment: Yeah - that tells me that the network card is working fine. What to you get if you do a `route print`?

Comment: I get the following:
IPv4 Route Table
0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.101 (IP address I filled in myself)
127.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 on-link 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 255.255.255.255 on-link 127.0.0.1

this goes on for a while, do I need to type all the addresses? And do I need to let my PC configure my IP again?

Comment: [[[[ 

Network: 0.0.0.0, 
Netmask: 0.0.0.0,
Gateway: 192.168.1.1,
Interface: 192.168.1.101 ]]]] 

That's the important bit, and if your local IP is indeed 1.101 you should be able to ping 1.1 no problem. Crazy question, but have you restarted the router at all?

Comment: The 192.168.1.1 did I fill in myself. If I select that my IP address is obtained automatically then the 168.192.1.1 does not show up on 'route print'.

Yes, restarted it several times. Other connection are working via that same router, though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11296/discussion-between-r3mus-and-user1879242)